# How to attach grenades to the walls?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

I have been playing Gears of War 3 a lot lately and have already prestiged once.

Online, I see people **attaching** their grenades onto columns and walls to kill or blind the opposition. I have yet to find out how they do this.

Can anyone show me an Xbox 360 controller image with the button(s) used to put a grenade on a wall? Thanks!

Comment: I think it's the reload button (default rb) while in cover with the grenade equipped. I may be wrong though- I haven't played in ages.

Comment: you have the game?

Comment: I meant you have Xbox 360?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the grenade in your hand, walk up the surface you intend to plant it on and press the melee button (default is "B"). If it doesn't work you might just need to get closer.

Additionally to planting grenades on walls and pillars and such, you can also do this to enemies. It is a very effective tactic to dispatching some of the bigger guys.

Comment: Thanks! What is your Gamertag so I may add you and try it myself :D

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer have the game. Sorry!

Comment: As I recall, your character will hold the grenade in a different position when they are ready to attach the grenade.